# Refs and the DOM in react native

Tags: react-native

I am working on [swipeListView](https://github.com/jemise111/react-native-swipe-list-view) in react native and they have line which state

> If you are using the standalone  you can just keep a ref to the component and call **closeRow()** on that ref.

But how do I create a ref and and how do I call it.

and also react native claims not to use the ref much and why is it so.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about React Native but here's how you create ref's in a React component.

```
<Component
      ref={instance => {
        this.componentReference = instance;
      }}
    />
//Once you create a ref, you can access it in any of your function using this.ref (Like here it would be this.componentReference).
```

To answer your 2nd question, refs are considered a bad practice because they are nothing but a workaround to directly access your DOM element. React wants you to avoid direct DOM manipulations since you essentially loose the benefits and speed of React virtual DOM and your state gets cluttered since you directly manipulate your DOM.